# Using chage and grep command for password expire

Tags: linux, grep, cut

My chage -l $person commmand works perfectly to get all of the password information to the screen, but I need to use grep and cut commands in order to get the password expires date. I cannot use the awk commmand, as we haven't learnt it in class yet, so I am stuck with cut and grep to get the line i need.

```
Last password change                                    : Feb 19, 2020
Password expires                                        : Jun 18, 2020
Password inactive                                       : Jun 28, 2020
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 120
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 10
```

I tried

```
chage -l "$person" | grep 'Password expires' | cut -d ':'
```

how is this wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: `cut -d:` will split the output at the `:` characters.

Comment: `grep 'Password expires'` will select that line from the output.

Comment: ```chage -l "$person" | grep 'Password expires' | cut -d ':' how is this wrong?

Comment: You need a `-f` option to `cut` to tell it which fields to print.

Comment: But the -f only takes columns not rows?

Comment: `grep` selects the row, `cut` selects the column.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `-f` option to `cut` to tell it which column to print.

```
chage -l "$person" | grep 'Password expires' | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was working on the the past two days trying to get it to work, I have one last question for you, how do I get that into a variable so I can say: "Password expires: June 2020"

Comment: variable=$(command)` sets the variable to the output of the command.

Comment: Your textbook or tutorial must explain that somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, and our textbook mainly is about how Operating systems and stuff works, less based on the code that goes into it, before corona we would learn all code in class